# How to use array in this program?

Tags: c++

> Students can pay their fees in Installments in classes. A student can
>   decide the number of installments.
>
> While paying the installment amount, the person can pay less or more
>   than the installment amount. If person is paying more than the
>   installment amount, the excess amount should be deducted from the next
>   installment(s). If person is paying less than the installment amount,
>   then ask the person for what to do with the remaining amount: Add it
>   to the next installment  or create a new installment.
>
> 1. Input 1: First create the installment structure with the input from the student.
>      Amount: Rs. 10,000
>      Number of Installment: 4
>      Output  1: Installment Structure: [2500, 2500, 2500, 2500]
>
>    2.Input 2: Student visits the coaching classes and paid Rs, 3000 for the 1st installment and ask to adjust the excess amount from the next
>      installment.
>      Amount paid: Rs. 3,000
>      Output 2: Installment Structure: [3000, 2000, 2500, 2500]
>
>    3.Input 3: Student visits the coaching classes and paid Rs, 1500 for the 2nd installment and ask to add the rest amount in the next
>      installment.
>      Amount paid: Rs. 1,500
>      Output 3: Installment Structure: [3000, 1500, 3000, 2500]
>
>    4.Input 4: Student visits the coaching classes and paid Rs, 2000 for the 3rd installment and ask to create a new installment for the rest
>      of the amount.
>      Amount paid: Rs. 2,000
>      Output 4: Installment Structure: [3000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 1000]
>
> Program should be in c++

I have tried this one but unable to get 2,3,4 steps of the code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int amount,no_of_installment,c,remaining;
cout <<"Enter Amount";
cin>>amount;

cout <<"Enter No of installments";
cin>>no_of_installment;

cout <<"You Entered Amount"<<amount<<endl;
cout <<"You Entered No of Installments"<<no_of_installment<<endl;
for(int i=1;i<=no_of_installment;i++)
{

c = amount/no_of_installment;
remaining = amount -c;
cout<<remaining<<endl;

}
   cout <<"Remaining Amount"<<remaining<<endl;



   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to use an array or can you use `std::vector`?  The `std::vector` manages memory automatically, can grow dynamically and is easier to pass to functions.

Comment: You can try it.

Comment: If that is the first step then you did it wrong because that will output 7500 not 2500

Comment: @AniketMainkar We don't use raw arrays in c++, period!

Answer (score 0):

Since the question asks how to use an array

```
int main()
{
int amount,no_of_installment;

cout <<"Enter Amount";
cin>>amount;

cout <<"Enter No of installments";
cin>>no_of_installment;
vector<int> v;

cout <<"You Entered Amount"<<amount<<endl;
cout <<"You Entered No of Installments"<<no_of_installment<<endl;
cout << "Installment Structure: ["
for(int i = 0;no_of_installment > 0;i++,no_of_installment--)
{
v.push_back(amount/no_of_installment);
amount = amount - v[i];
cout << v[i];
if(i < 3)
cout << ",";
}
cout << "]" << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int array[no_of_installment];`, with `no_of_installment` not known at compile time, is a common compiler extension but is NOT standard C++.

Comment: @aschepler is that better?

Comment: or I could have done this: `int *array = new int[no_of_installment];`

Comment: @aschepler so what I had before would give me an error because `array[no_of_installment]` is known at run time and not at compile time

Comment: @Tyger I need that structure. I Tried What You did over there But this is same as what I have done.

Comment: @AniketMainkar you need the output to look like `installment structure: [2500, 2500, 2500, 2500]`?

Comment: Why do people Downvote the question I Dont Understand! :(

Comment: @AniketMainkar I have no idea why, your question is better than most look at my answer i fixed the mistakes is that what you wanted?

Comment: @tyger I dont want to break the loop
If should take next installment amount and next element should be affected
If he pays more than installment amount the next installment amount be shown less and he pays less installment amount it should be added.